# How can a SharePoint Online wiki page library be migrated to another SharePoint Online tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, pnp-powershell, content-migration

We are trying to move a SharePoint Online wiki page library from one SharePoint Online tenant to another (Office 365). There is no functionality within Sharepoint to do this, and it is too expensive to use a third-party app.

**We have tried the following:**

- Microsoft's **SharePoint Migration Tool** does not support SharePoint Online to SharePoint Online migration.
- We have looked into **Mover** (**https://mover.io/** - acquired by Microsoft) and are currently resolving some global administrator access issues for it. (Results pending)
- We have seen many suggestions to create a **template** of the site, but wiki sites are publishing-based and cannot be created into a template.
- We have accessed the site files in **Windows Explorer** through the Sharepoint Classic interface (in Win7 Internet Explorer x32), but it does not copy site contents, only site layouts. Also, the destination site breaks / disappears when source files are removed or replaced with files from another site.
- We have used **Powershell PnP** to download and copy site files to another site, but it does not copy wiki pages, only site pages.

Has anyone had any success with this? Any advice/ideas would be appreciated.